# Determining P values after using cor function to test significance in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am new to R and am using the cor function (and specifically Spearman) to determine if there is a significant correlation between the passage of time (indicated in column 1) and the increase in frequencies of variables in the other 100,001 columns in my dataframe. In otherwords, I am testing to see if there is a correlation between column 1 and column 2-100,001 in turn.

So, currently, I import a CSV file into R, and it is transformed into a dataset (test_data_fix).
Currently, I use the following code, and it returns a dataframe with all my column labels alongside all of the the associated Spearman correlation values:

`x <- test_data_fix[1:100001]
 y <- test_data_fix[1]
 corrs_test <- round(cor(x, y, method = "spearman", use="complete.obs"), 3)`

However, I am trying to also find the P values and have these as one of the columns in my returned dataframe. I know that if I use cor.test I can check the p-values for individual correlations one at a time or using corr.test returns the values for every single possible correlation. However, is there a way that I can just return the p-values for the test of correlation between just column 1 and all subsequent columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate. This method, for example, gives you the matrix of p-values similar to how `cor` gives you the correlation value for each column-column combination.

```
myfunc <- function(i,j) mapply(function(a,b) cor.test(mtcars[[a]], mtcars[[b]])$p.value, i, j)
mt <- mtcars[1:5]
outer(seq_len(ncol(mt)), seq_len(ncol(mt)), myfunc)
#              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
# [1,] 0.000000e+00 6.112687e-10 9.380327e-10 1.787835e-07 1.776240e-05
# [2,] 6.112687e-10 0.000000e+00 1.802838e-12 3.477861e-09 8.244636e-06
# [3,] 9.380327e-10 1.802838e-12 0.000000e+00 7.142679e-08 5.282022e-06
# [4,] 1.787835e-07 3.477861e-09 7.142679e-08 0.000000e+00 9.988772e-03
# [5,] 1.776240e-05 8.244636e-06 5.282022e-06 9.988772e-03 0.000000e+00
```

or even better, with names (thanks @RyanD):

```
outer(mt, mt, Vectorize(function(a, b) cor.test(a, b)$p.value)) 
#               mpg          cyl         disp           hp         drat
# mpg  0.000000e+00 6.112687e-10 9.380327e-10 1.787835e-07 1.776240e-05
# cyl  6.112687e-10 0.000000e+00 1.802838e-12 3.477861e-09 8.244636e-06
# disp 9.380327e-10 1.802838e-12 0.000000e+00 7.142679e-08 5.282022e-06
# hp   1.787835e-07 3.477861e-09 7.142679e-08 0.000000e+00 9.988772e-03
# drat 1.776240e-05 8.244636e-06 5.282022e-06 9.988772e-03 0.000000e+00
```

If you need a comparison of just one column against all others, then:

```
outer(1, seq_len(ncol(mt)), myfunc)
#      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        [,5]
# [1,]    0 6.112687e-10 9.380327e-10 1.787835e-07 1.77624e-05
outer(mt[1], mt, Vectorize(function(a, b) cor.test(a, b)$p.value)) 
#     mpg          cyl         disp           hp        drat
# mpg   0 6.112687e-10 9.380327e-10 1.787835e-07 1.77624e-05
```

... but to apply this as a column in your `data.frame` does not make sense: to add a column suggests that (say) the first returned p-value would be associated with the other values in that first row, definitely not the case.

Comment: Thank you for this! Can I just double check that it's correct for the p-values returned by this method to differ from those calculated one-by-one. For instance, if I do "cor.test(1:32, mtcars$cyl)" (which I've been told is how to compare column one, here mpg, against a specified "other" column, in this case cyl) then it returns a p-value of 0.8753, which is clearly a lot higher than the 6.112687e-10 returned above. Or have I misunderstood something? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: `cor.test(1:32, mtcars$cyl)` runs the test between "cyl" and the literal vector of 1 through 32, how does it represent "mpg"? Try `cor.test(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)`.

Comment: And no, individual tests' p-values should match with this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Without data the following is untested but I believe it does what you want.

It uses `sapply` to run tests of each of the columns 2 to 100001 as `x` and the first column as `y`.

```
cor_test_results <- sapply(test_data_fix[-1], function(x)
  cor.test(x, y = test_data_fix[[1]], method = "spearman")$p.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cor.test()` can indeed provide you with a p-value (although it might be problematic with ties).

That said, at a bigger level, consider asking yourself whether it makes sense to group 100,000 columns into one sample. It's entirely possible that not only do they represent distinct samples, but they may also be sampling different populations (although it's hard to tell not knowing the data).

Also, if you do decide to go with one-to-one comparisons, your results will be pretty much uninterpretable if you don't apply some multiple testing adjustment of sorts (which will come at a cost of your ability to detect true positives).